# Run function when element was created

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some elements created by v-for. How can I run the function only once by keeping 'for every element creation' as a condition .

```
<div v-for"value in values">
   <div @ function(value, domElement) if value.bool===true @>
              </div>
```

Comment: That's unusual. You probably want something else. Why do you want to execute a function?

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way, IMO, would be to make each of those elements a Vue Component & pass the function down as a prop.

File One

```
<div v-for="value in values">
   <Custom-Component :propValue="value" :propFunction="functionYouNeed" />
</div>
```

Custom Component

```
<template>
  <div> {{propValue.value}} </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   props: ['propFunction', 'propValue'],
   created(){
      if (this.propValue.bool === true) { 
         this.propFunction()
      }
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I'd recommend, as well, although I get the feeling that OP's use case might be avoidable in the first place.

Comment: I'd also recommend if it was about component. But OP seems to do it in elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so clear what exactly you want:

> `<div @ function(value, domElement) if value.bool===true @>`

So, here's all possible solutions you want to implement.

You can bind the method using [`once`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) modifier:

```
<div @click.once="yourMethod">
```

Or, if you want not to change the content then you can use [`v-once`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once):

```
<div v-once>{{ neverChanged }}</div>
```

But if you just need to use the function when it was created then call the function inside created property and do not bind the method anywhere else.

```
created() {
  if(condition) {
    this.yourMethod()
  }
}
```